# $\frac{\partial}{\partial r} $ $\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta }$ with respect of $\frac{\partial}{\partial x} $ $\frac{\partial}{\partial y }$

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

Let $x,y$ be  the usual functions in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and let $U=\mathbb{R}^2-\{(x,0): x\ge 0\} $.

Consider the polar coordinates $x=r\text{cos}\theta $ , $y=r\text{sin}\theta $
$\:r>0, \: \: 0<\theta<2\pi$

write $\frac{\partial}{\partial r} $, $\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta }$ with respect of $\frac{\partial}{\partial x} $, $\frac{\partial}{\partial y }$

---

I tried using the proposition (for the $id$ maps) that says if $M $ is a smooth manifold and $(U,φ=(x^1,...,x^n))$, $(V,ψ=y^1,...,y^n)$ are maps at $p\in M$ then

$\frac{\partial}{\partial y^j}=\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{\partial x^i}{\partial y^j}(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i})$

but I couldn't figure it out, if my idea is correct how should I carry on ?

Comment: Where are you stuck? It seems to me your idea is correct.

Comment: Your idea is correct, I always like to write out the differential of the coordinate function as a matrix then map basis vectors in one tangent space to basis vectors in another whenever I get unsure of this formula.

Comment: @ChristopherQuinnLaFondJr. The differential matrix you are referring to is just the jacobian right? Meaning $\left [\frac{\partial F^i}{\partial x^j} \right ]=\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial x}{\partial r}  &\frac{\partial x}{\partial \theta } \\ 
 \frac{\partial y}{\partial r}& \frac{\partial y}{\partial \theta }
\end{bmatrix}  $ with $\frac{\partial x}{\partial r}=\cos \vartheta$

Comment: Yes that’s exactly correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're on the right track. Here, your manifold $M$ is $\mathbb{R}^2$, and your "charts" mean your (local) coordinates, so $(x^1, x^2) = (x,y)$, and $(y^1, y^2) = (r, \theta)$.

Try applying the formula you wrote, and see what comes out :)

Comment: The polar coordinates  confused me a lot, I couldn't find $(x^1,x^2)$ and $(y^1,y^2)$. so we have that $\frac{\partial }{\partial r}=\frac{\partial x }{\partial r}\frac{\partial }{\partial x}+\frac{\partial y }{\partial r}\frac{\partial }{\partial y}=\cos \theta \frac{\partial }{\partial x}+\sin \vartheta \frac{\partial }{\partial y}$, correct ?

Comment: Yes, exactly :)